# Writing out text with double double quotes - Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, string, text

I'm trying to take the text output of a query to an SSD (pulling a log page, similar to pulling SMART data.  I'm then trying to write this text data out of a log file I update periodically.

My problem happens when the log data for some drives has double double-quotes as a placeholder for a blank field.  Here is a snippet of the input:

VER            0x10200
VID            0x15b7
BoardRev       0x0
BootLoadRev    ""

When this gets written out (appended) to my own log file, the text gets replaced with several null characters and then when I try to open all the text editors tell me it's corrupted.

The "" characters are replaced by something like this on my Linux system:

BootLoadRev "\00\00\00\00"

Some fields are even longer with the \00 characters.  If the "" is not there, things write out OK.

The code is similar to this:

```
f=open(fileName, 'w')
test_bench.send_command('get_log_page')
identify_data = test_bench.get_data_in()
f.write(identify_data)
f.close()
```

Is there a way to send this text to a file w/o these nulls causing problems?

Comment: Please include an **exact** reproducer -- solving this means knowing exactly what's wrong in detail. (If your data is UTF-32 encoded, for instance, that would result in *three* NULs before every character; if you're just getting literal NULs from your data source, there's another possible source, &c). As it is, there's not enough information to determine the immediate cause with precision and certainty.

Comment: If you logged `repr(identify_data)` from your Python, btw, that would be a place to start.

Comment: ...to be very clear, what's suspect here is the code within `test_bench`. You seem to have reached the conclusion that "quote cause NULs", but there's no backing for that belief -- it's just as likely that "quotes surround string, and strings from this source contain NULs". Because a NUL isn't rendered when it's sent straight to a terminal (for historical reasons -- when terminals were hardware that read data from serial lines, you were able to send a NUL on that serial line to tell it not to do anything, and could rely on the time required for NULs to tie up the serial line for timing [...]

Comment: [...] purposes), if you're normally just directly printing your `test_bench` content, you may simply not know the NULs are there (despite them *always* being there, even when *not* rendering to a file) because your terminal isn't rendering them.

Comment: Anyhow: If you can't provide a reproducer that recreates this problem without `test_bench`, then you've proved it's not a problem with writing strings in Python, but a problem with `test_bench`. This kind of opportunity to determine a problem's scope by determining what's needed to reproduce it is part of why we have the policy of requiring questions on this site to have a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ralfhtp, ...every **C** string is terminated with it. That's not true of Pascal-style strings (stored with length out-of-band), which Python uses.

Comment: yes you are right again, i delete the comment

Comment: I tried to take 'test_bench' out by writing a short script that sends the log page to the terminal.  This prints OK.  If I simply redirect that terminal output to a file (script > log_page.txt) I get the nulls in the txt file.    For example, gedit gives me this warning:  "The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is Python 2 (and that your content is thus what Python 3 would call a bytestring), and that your intended data format is raw ASCII, the trivial solution is simply to remove the NULs from your content before you write to disk:

```
f.write(identify_data.replace('\0', ''))
```